# How to disable sorting for selected columns in PrimeNG table?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to disable sorting of selected columns based on Boolean value in PrimeNG table.
Below is my columns array

```
cols = [
    { field: 'name', header: 'Name', sort: true },
    { field: 'age', header: 'Age', sort: true },
    { field: 'gender', header: 'Gender', sort: false },
    { field: 'status', header: 'Status', sort: false }
  ];
```

Some of the columns having `sort` value as `false` and I need to disable those columns from sorting.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="persons" [resizableColumns]="true" sortField="name" sortMode="single">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th pResizableColumn  *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" [pSortableColumnDisabled]="col.field === 'name' || col.field === 'age'">
                <div class="tb-heading">{{col.header}}</div>
                <div class="sort-icons-container">
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I can use above code for disabling columns i.e., `name` and `age` by using `pSortableColumnDisabled` but I don't want to hardcode the column names like above as these columns will be passed dynamically by parent component.

Is there any way to disable the columns based on respective `sort` Boolean value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending sometime on internet found the solution for above problem  https://embed.plnkr.co/egBhS1DJhY2Ud1ByfGBp/

Changed the hardcoded condition from

```
[pSortableColumn]="col.field" [pSortableColumnDisabled]="col.field === 'name' || col.field === 'age'"
```

to

```
[pSortableColumnDisabled]="!col.sort ? true : false"
```